# How to check EC2 security group id using Powershell command?

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-powershell

How to check EC2 security group ID using PowerShell command?

I am new to PowerShell. I tried to browse but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: What information you are looking for a security group id and what have you browsed? Powershell ref. for AWS is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/Index.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

below command will get EC2 security group ID and Group Name

```
Get-EC2SecurityGroup|select groupname, groupid
```